# How to improve OCR Accuracy which use tesseract?

Tags: android, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am working on OCR application . I have used this [this Demo](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr)! with the help of Tesseract. Its working fine . But the Problem is in Accuracy So How to improve accuracy through code? I have seen many links but not getting help.Any one can help on this.

And I have worked on [other demos also](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/) & [this one](https://github.com/komamitsu/Android-OCRSample)!
But still there is on 40 to 50 %  accuracy . I am looking from last 7 days for the accuracy
I have seen **Text Cleaner** & **imagemagick** tools but not understand & how to use this in my code for image processing.

Any Help would be Appreciated!

Thanks & Warm Regards,

Comment: Did you found any solution for how to improve OCR accuracy??